# Predict car accidents with tensorflow

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, tensorflow, deep-learning

So the task is kinda simple. As far as I know machine learning I know that it is possible, I just don't now the way to do it.

So basically I want to predict how many car accidents there will be in my city. I have data of weather conditions and how much there was accidents from past and to test or validate my model I want to use the latest accident data.

```
weather = [[20150601 130100, 23, 60], #[year_month_day hours_mins_secs, temperature_C, humidity_%]
[20150601 130100, 23, 50],
[20150601 130200, 23, 51],
# ...
[20150601 132300, 23, 49]]

accidents = [[20150601 130700, 1], #[year_month_day hours_mins_secs, count_of_accidents
[20150601 1301000, 2], 
[20150601 1301100, 1], 
# ... 
[20150601 132300, 1]]
```

So now I want to predict accident count for every minute based on temperature and humidity per date (note that sometimes the input data is not provided every minute, and there is time gaps). To improve my model I want to feed it with new accident and weather data each day.
The bottom line is that at the end we'll have the program that can say when there will be an accident based on weather, thus it can say it is safe or not safe to drive today. In future I'll update it with other data sets but for now let's train it this way.
So the question is how to make this happen on tensorflow? Can someone please help?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Why are you using tensorflow for this?  It sounds like a straight regression problem to me...

Comment: @flyingmeatball Couse that is the whole purpose of task - to make it work with deep neural network. And especially with Tensor flow.

Comment: Since you have series data, perhaps you can try RNN.

Comment: @SungKim Ok, that seams to work. Maybe there is some working code example which i can take as a starting point?

Comment: Since it's a bit long, I put it in the answer. Let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

There will be many ways to handle this. However, since you have series data, and car accidents may be actually related to the t-n weather data, RNN might be a good start.

Please see the RNN (LSTM) based classification example at https://github.com/nlintz/TensorFlow-Tutorials/blob/master/7_lstm.py.

I'm also interested in this. Let me know how it goes.